# PF Calendar in Dialog nulls Java Property in UiComponent#visitTree

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Prerequisites:

- xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
- javax.faces.component.UIComponent

Setup:

- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.1.2
- org.glassfish:javax.faces:jar:2.2.14
- Tomcat 8.5.28
- Proprietary OR Mapper

```
@Property
private Calendar cal;
```

```
public Calendar getCal() {
  return ORMapper.getProperty(this, "cal");
}
```

Functional setup:
p:commandButton that during its action executes code (that leads to the error) and then opens a dialogue which contains

```
<p:calendar id="cal" value="#{bean.model.cal}" />
```

Execution:
During Invoke Application of the commandButton (action) we traverse a section of the DOM tree that does NOT contain the dialogue (i.e. that dialogue is not a child of component) using

```
component.visitTree(
  VisitContext.createVisitContext(
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), 
    null, 
    Collections.singleton(VisitHint.SKIP_UNRENDERED)),
  (context, component) -> {
    ...
    return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
  }
);
```

Before the tree execution
model.cal = value
model.getCal() = value

Errorneous behaviour:
After the tree execution
model.cal = null
model.getCal() = value

This then leads to an error when validating the model which has a violation on e.g. @NotNull on the property (not the getter)

Notes:

- Using IntelliJ attempts where made to find the change: Field Access/Modification breakpoints, calls to get/setter breakpoints, EL Method Invoker breakpoints
- Removing the visitTree call fixes the Problem
- Removing the element from the dialogue fixes the problem
- Later on the value is set again, when couldnt be figured out either

Comment: I can only say one thing: [mcve]

Comment: I tried to create one but its hard as the applicational context is very complicated. I hope someone can provide info without one